transform-origin applied to a <clipPath> is wrong on retina displays
Context:
I'm trying to reveal an element on page scroll using the shape of a "blob" with a CSS animation-timeline animation so the code must be tested on a recent Edge or Chrome browser.
The element (a <div>) has a clip-path: url(#blob) where #blob is the id of a <clipPath> element contained in a SVG: this element has clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox" and the coordinates of the <path> create a shape of a blob.
The <clipPath> is initially scaled to 0 and the animation linked to the animation-timeline makes it scale to 2.5.

Problem:
The issue is in the transform-origin of the <clipPath> element.
On a retina display the origin of the scale transformation is wrong, while on non-retina display is correct1.
Here is the minimal code to reproduce the issue (but I also made a demo on Codepen)


body { 
   margin: 0;
   view-timeline: --body;
   min-block-size: 300vh; 
}

div {
   position: sticky;
   top: 0;
   display: grid;
   place-content: center;
   block-size: 100vh;
   background: linear-gradient(#83a3ac, #df9784);
   clip-path: url("#blob");

   h1 {
      font: 7rem "system-ui";
      color: #fff;
   }
}

svg {
   block-size: 0;
   inline-size: 0;

   clipPath {
      transform-origin: 50vw 50vh;
      transform: scale(0);
      animation: linear clippath 1 forwards;
      animation-timeline: --body;
      animation-range: exit-crossing 25vh exit-crossing 275vh;   
   }
}

@keyframes clippath { to { transform: scale(2.5) }}
<body>
  <div>
     <h1>Hello, World</h1>
  </div>


  <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
       aria-hidden="true" focusable="false">

     <clipPath id="blob" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">
        <path d="M0.8338,0.1121c0.0818,0.0416,0.1468,
           0.1134,0.1623,0.1922c0.0158,0.0788-0.0178,
           0.1642-0.0397,0.2459c-0.0216,0.0819-0.0316,
           0.1598-0.0652,0.2489c-0.0338,0.089-0.0909,
           0.1882-0.1696,0.1995c-0.0789,0.0115-0.1794
           -0.065-0.2937-0.096c-0.1147-0.0312-0.2437
           -0.0172-0.3109-0.065c-0.0674-0.0478-0.0726
           -0.1574-0.0887-0.2649c-0.0158-0.1076-0.0412
           -0.2135-0.0201-0.3188c0.0208-0.1054,0.0886
           -0.2096,0.1875-0.2447c0.0986-0.0351,0.2551
           -0.0011,0.3824,0.0221C0.6536,0.0593,0.7519,
           0.0703,0.8338,0.1121z"/>
    </clipPath>   
  </svg>
</body>




What I actually see?

(click to see the animated gif: on the left a retina display, on the right a non-retina display)

What I tried?
I found a workaround with a mediaquery for retina displays
 clipPath {
    transform-origin: 50vw 50vh;
    @media (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2) { 
       transform-origin: 100vw 100vh;
    }
    ...
 }

but I'm not sure this could be a consistent approach. What am I doing wrong?

Footnotes/edits
1: tested with a Macbook Air 13" (2024) and iMac 27" (2017) and various non-retina displays

Update
Opened an issue on Chromium bugtracker, bug confirmed
https://issues.chromium.org/issues/366293477

What devices are you using to test the Retina display behaviour?

I tested with a MacBook air 13" and an iMac 27"

As you've mentioned Apple devices – does it run on MacOS safari? At least iOS safari and linux web/epiphany and midori (also webkit based) also seem to struggle with this approach.

@herrstrietzel no, safari doesn't support CSS scroll animations yet.
